# How can I measure rotation on a cog wheel?

Tags: sensor

The cog wheel is 40 mm in diameter and is being rotated by a motor at 2.5 rpm. This cog wheel is inside a turntable that is used as an exhibit stand. Rotation will only be between 0-360 degrees i.e one cycle only, and then back to 0. I need to measure the degrees of rotation on this cog wheel. any suggestions will be really appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many possible methods.

- Zero position can provide a reset signal (microswitch or magnet and hall cell or reed) or ...
- Cog teeth can be counted "there and back again". How depends on material.
  If ferrous ("magnetic") they can use an inductive sensor and magnet or hall sensor and magnet or ...
  Teeth of any material can be sensed optically.
  Or capacitively in some cases.
  Or sense inductive change in a coil in some cases.

  Having two sensors offset by 1/2  a tooth pitch gives two quadrature signals which are 90 degrees out of phase so you can determine direction from pattern received. (See diagram and text below).
- A stepper motor will allow turntable to be stepped N steps.
  Count the steps - as long as no-slippage can be guaranteed.
- Turntable can have coder tracks on inside rim or on under surface.
  If this is a one off job or a small number the track(s) can be hand drawn with marker pen (and due care).
  [Wikipedia - rotary encoders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder)

  One track of 10101010... gives position change count.
  The first diagram below shows radial marks of full radius length but they can be just a line of dark/light marks at the sensor location.

[image]

eg [from this useful page](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/circuits/wheelEncoder.html)

[image]

Two tracks offset 1/2 a mark (1/4 of a 1-0 cycle) allows direction and count and speed.

[image]

N tracks and sensors allows position determination to 1/N^2 of a revolution.
 eg if you use 8 tracks and 8 optical sensors you can determine absolute psition to 1 part in 256 or 360/256 ~=1.5 degree steps.

The "obvious" method is a standard binary code.
 Here the outer track provides 01010101 to give 8 positions around 360 degrees.
 The next track in produces 00110011
 The next 00001111
This gives standard binary code 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111, ...

[image]

HOWEVER, in places two bits change at once and sensor misalignment or noise can lead to false codes. eg at he boundary from 011 to 100
 if the left hand bit changed early to give code 111 before the x11 bits changes to x00 then he codes sequence may appear to be 011, 111, 100 or in decimal 3, 7, 4.
 Suitable software can deal with this, but an alternative and historical approach is to use codes that only alter 1 bit at any boundary. These are named Gray codes after Bell Labs scientist the late Frank Gray (1887 - 1969) who patented the concept in 1953.

The diagram below shows a 3 bit Gray coded disk in which only one bit changes at any boundary. The sequence here is (traversing anticlockwise, outer track = LSB):
 000, 001, 011, 010, 110, 111, 101, 100, ...
 or in decimal
 0, 1, 3, 2, 6, 7, 5, 4, ...

[image]

And more ...

Answer (score 2):

This is often done with a rotary encoder:

[image]

The slotted wheel is positioned between the optointerrupter and gives a pulse every time a cog passes the light beam. This one is low resolution; it only gives 16 edges per revolution, so that a 22.5 degrees resolution, but similar slotted wheels exist which give you sub-degree resolution. You'll have to reset your pulse counter when the wheel is at the start position, which you should be able to detect to change rotation direction. This single photointerrupter will only allow you to detect rotation angle, not [rotation direction](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/15482/2064), but since you're driving the motor yourself you should know what the direction is.

Instead of this incremental decoder you can also use an absolute decoder. Unlike the incremental decoder this doesn't require you to continuously keep track of position by counting pulses. Instead the absolute decoder has multiple channels which give you coded word which gives you the absolute position.

[image]

This has the advantage that the position is also known after power-down. An incremental decoder will have to sync after power-down to a known position (return to zero).